# Pandas dataframe from URL json data - KeyError cannot index or filter by keys

Tags: python, json, pandas

```
import pandas as pd

url = "https://api.reserve.albertaparks.ca/api/public/campgrounds/62/availability?campingType=campsite" \
      "&arrivalDt=01-Aug-2021&departureDt=13-Aug-2021&unitSize=40&siteType=VEH"
result = pd.read_json(url)
print(result)

df = pd.DataFrame(result)
df = df[df['available']]
df.set_index('date', inplace=True)
print(df)
```

I'm trying to return only results where 'available' = True and format the results like below without the table. Probably using tabulate but not sure.

| date | available | fcfs |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01-Aug-2021 | True | False |
| 02-Aug-2021 | True | False |
| 03-Aug-2021 | True | False |
| 04-Aug-2021 | True | False |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
result = pd.read_json(url)
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(result['availability'])
df = df.loc[lambda x: x['available']].set_index("date")
print(df) # or tabulate(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `json_normalize` from pandas package and then use normal filtering

```
df1 = pd.json_normalize(df.availability)
df2 = df1[df1['available']==True]

           date  available   fcfs
1   02-Aug-2021       True  False
2   03-Aug-2021       True  False
3   04-Aug-2021       True  False
4   05-Aug-2021       True  False
5   06-Aug-2021       True  False
7   08-Aug-2021       True  False
8   09-Aug-2021       True  False
9   10-Aug-2021       True  False
10  11-Aug-2021       True  False
11  12-Aug-2021       True  False
```

Comment: is it possible to run this code every 5 minutes and only print the results of there is a change?